# Removing elements with empty character "" in string vector

Tags: r

Using `read.csv`, I have a dataframe read from .csv file which has data arranged as following:

```
team1 team2 team3
Andy  Alice  Karen
Bob   Belle  Kyle
Chad  Carol  
      Diana
```

```
team <- read.csv("team.csv")
```

The data frame is of factor class and have dimension or 4x3. For `team1` and `team3` columns, the extra empty rows are show with `""`.
I want to extract the column as a vector using `as.character` conversion. But how do I shorten this vector exclude the `""` elements? For eg.:

`team1_list <- as.character(team$team1)` includes the trailing `""` element. I just want to have the vector of `("Andy", "Bob", "Chad")` and not `("Andy", "Bob", "Chad", "")`

Comment: Try this `team1_list <- as.character(team$team1[team$team1!=""])` or `team1_list <- as.character(team$team1[levels(team$team1)!=""])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As no data is present you can try one of these options:

Option 1:

```
#Code1
team1_list <- as.character(team$team1[team$team1!=""])
```

Option 2:

```
#Code2
team1_list <- as.character(team$team1[levels(team$team1)!=""])
```

Answer (score 10):

It is easier to use `nzchar` from `base R`

```
str1[nzchar(str1)]
#[1] "Andy" "Bob"  "Chad"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Andy", "Bob", "Chad", "")
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option using `stri_remove_empty` of `stringi` package to remove empty string of vector.

```
library(stringi)
str <- c("Andy", "Bob", "Chad", "")
team1_list <- as.character(stri_remove_empty(str, na_empty = FALSE))
team1_list
#[1] "Andy" "Bob"  "Chad"
```

Comment: This function is super useful.